# Блок if или цикл в одну строчку

Tags: python

Добрый день.

Насколько допустимо в Python записывать очень короткие блоки if и циклы в одну строчку? Существуют ли официальные рекомендации по этому вопросу?

Я имею в виду что-то, похожее на один из следующих вариантов:

```
if check: continue

if x.param: x.modify()

while x.value: x.rotate()
```

На мой взгляд, так смотрится гораздо лучше, особенно если несколько подобных коротких блоков идут друг за другом - иначе получалась бы уродская "гребёнка".
Прав ли я?

Comment: Если работаешь в одиночку то допустимо, иначе строго следуем стандартам. На практике бывают цепочки длиной в несколько строк, если их не разбивать, то читать сложно. Это тут короткая строка, на практике будет текущий комментарий в виде вставки текста. Дальше его обработка. Просто не читаемо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Синтаксис Python позволяет использовать такие конструкции, но в [**pep8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) их использование не рекомендуется:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
>   generally discouraged.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah':
>     do_blah_thing()
> do_one()
> do_two()
> do_three()
> ```
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
> ```